# Spring security @notation for IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY?

Tags: spring-security

I am simply trying to allow a user access to a method if they are authenticated, but nothing I am doing seems to work. Is there a way to just check if the user has been authenticated?  The following still denies the user even when authenticated... Is there a built in role for an authenticated user?

```
@RequestMapping("/secure")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')")
public String secure(ModelMap map){
    return("secure");
}
```

Answer (score 16):

`IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` is not a role - it is a pre-defined credential (aka 'magic' string) recognized by the `AuthenticatedVoter` to indicate that you have logged in.  This voter also supports anonymous and remember-me login.

Roles are processed by the RoleVoter which recognizes any sting starting with "ROLE_" (prefix is configurable). Thus `hasRole('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')` doesn't work because it's not a role. `@RolesAllowed("IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY")` wouldn't work for the same reason.

When using Spring expression language, the correct expression is:

```
 @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
```

Alternatively, you can use:

```
 @Secured("IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY")
```

No custom classes are required - both voters are enabled by default.

Answer (score 1):

`hasRole('ROLE_USER')` is the traditional name for any user who is authenticated. You would typically use `ROLE_ANONYMOUS` for parts where you don't care if the person is authenticated or not.

(Added later:)

I think you will need to implement a custom [AccessDecisionVoter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/AccessDecisionVoter.html) that will always vote `ACCESS_GRANTED` whenever the parameter authentication has isAuthenticated() true, and the `CONFIG_ATTRIBUTE` is `ROLE_USER` or similar.

There is further discussion of this in this [forum discussion](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=83198), giving details of a web.xml and other config.

Comment: I am using the default ldap-authentication-provider with no role mapping.  When a user is authenticated, I can see in the logging: "[DEBUG,DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator] Roles from search: []" is there a way to simply set a role for any user that is authenticated vs searching the ldap directory?

Answer (score 1):

In your custom `UserDetailService` implementation just add the Role "IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" to the `User` object before it's returned.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have ended up using:

```
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
@PreAuthorize("isFullyAuthenticated()")
```